# Did Bartholomew Kuma intend to send the crew to different places or was it by chance?

Tags: one-piece

Did Bartholomew Kuma plan to send all of the crew members to different places or is it just a coincidence that he helped all of them in different ways?

Comment: He definitely didn't do it by accident. It was his last action while he still had his personality. Later he says, "I work for the Revolutionary Army. Since we have a connection, I want to help this group escape."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kuma definitively knew what he did. Otherwise Zoro wouldn't have landed on Mihawk's island.

Also, I found this:

> Sentomaru reveals that Kuma has the ability to make people fly through the sky to far away places. A Monster Chopper runs wild, trying to attack Sentomaru. Rayleigh is still seen dueling Kizaru, using swords while Nami reflects on Kuma's ability, where it was first shown at Thriller Bark.
>
> Kuma Attacking Pacifista
> Kuma intercepting a Pacifista.
> She remembers that Perona mysteriously vanished. Luffy asks Sentomaru where Zoro could have gone, and Sentomaru says that anyone that gets **touched by Kuma's paws would sail through three days and three nights and the destination would only be known by Kuma. An outraged Sanji gets ready to battle Kuma**, while PX-1 tries to attack Usopp from behind, using a beam attack. Kuma then uses his Devil Fruit ability to send PX-1 away, which enraged Sentomaru.

source: [One Piece Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bartholomew_Kuma)

Comment: if u are satisfied with my answer pleas mark it as answer.